# stratified random sampling with different ratios for group variables

Tags: python, r, sampling

I want to create a sample of size **n=10** using **two-stage stratified random sampling** with **N=5051** observations. That means there are **2 factors(strata)** each named **"hy"** and **"ge"** in this case. Here's my dataset.

```
set.seed(1)
df <-data.table()
df
     no    hy    ge
1     1     4     2
2     2     4     1
3     3     4     1
4     4     4     1
5     5     3     2
6     6     4     1
7     7     4     2
8     8     4     3
9     9     4     3
10    10    4     3
# … with 5,041 more rows
```

And the number of elements in the population was organized by stratum as follows.
As you see **the combination of two factors' Stratum range from 1 to 14**.

```
df[ , .N, keyby = list(hy, ge)]
df[ , .N, keyby = list(hy)]
df[ , .N, keyby = list(ge)]

       hy ge  N   ratio           hy    N    ratio            ge    N   ratio
   1:  1  1  340   6.7        1:   1   1203   23.8       1:    1   888   17.6
   2:  1  2  778  15.4        2:   2   1036   20.5       2:    2  3266   64.7
   3:  1  3   85   1.7        3:   3   1207   23.9       3:    3   897   17.8
   4:  2  1  175   3.5        4:   4   1418   28.1
   5:  2  2  758  15.0        5:   5     97    1.9
   6:  2  3  103   2.0        6:   6     90    1.8
   7:  3  1  200   4.0
   8:  3  2  779  15.4
   9:  3  3  228   4.5
   10: 4  1  173   3.4
   11: 4  2  951  18.8
   12: 4  3  294   5.8
   13: 5  3   97   1.9
   14: 6  3   90   1.8
```

Next, I'm trying to stratified random sampling using the **strata()** function according to **the ratio of the stratum** of the two factors.

```
set.seed(2)
samp <- data.table(strata(df, c("hy", "ge"), size=, "srswor"))
```

You might have noticed that i'm having trouble because I don't know how to input the sample of size to fit the proportion of the population. Many examples I found on the internet all assume a common ratio for all the variables like below

```
set.seed(2)
#data.table(strata(df, c("hy", "ge"), rep(20,30), "srswor"))
#data.table(strata(df, c("hy", "ge"), c(3,3,3), "srswor"))
```

But what I want is to sample according to the ratio of the combinations of the two variables.
Of course, since the size of sample is too small, there are stratums that are not sampled proportionally, but I want to make it technically. How can I do that?

```
set.seed(2)
#data.table(strata(df, c("hy", "ge"), round(10 * prop.table(table(df$hy,df$ge)), 0), "srswor"))
```

I thought of a way to input **something like** size = round(10 * prop.table(table(df$hy)), 0) in the function but I have two variables and I don't know how to handle it. please help.